# metaprogramming access local variables

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    bar = 10
  end
  fiz = 5
end
```

Is there a possibility to get these local values (outside the class) ?

Comment: Wow, that's really frightening. I'd shy away from trying anything like that.

Comment: Are you getting `local_variables` mixed up with `@instance_variables`?

Comment: sure, it's only an exercise on ruby metaprogramming course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local variable in initialize would be lost.

You are able to get the value fiz outside of the class, but only upon defining that class, and recording the return of the definition of the class.

`return_of_class_definition = (class A ; fiz = 5 ; end)` would assign the value of fiz to the variable.

You can also use `binding` but of course, this means changing the class, which may not be allowed for the exercise.

```
class A
  bin = 15
  $binding = binding
end

p eval 'bin', $binding
```

Comment: Note that that only works because `fiz = 5` happens to be the last expression in the class body.

Comment: vgoff?  That's familiar.  A similar technique could be used to get the value of 'bar': class SonOfFoo << Foo
  def initialize
    bar = 10
  end
  fiz = 5
end
 class AA < A
  def initialize()
    puts super
  end
end

Comment: Please disregard most of the comment I just left.  (Editing problems.)  To get 'bar', create a subclass of Foo containing def initialize() puts super; end.

Comment: Exactly @sepp2k, and it feels like programming by side affect in this case, right?  Not like the more accepted 'last statement evaluated' being returned in a method.  But "Know the rules, so you know how to break them."

Answer (score 3):

No. Once a local variable goes out of scope (for bar that is when the `initialize` method has run - for `fiz` when the `end` of the class definition has been reached), it's gone. No trace left.

While a local variable is still in scope you can see it (well, its name) with `local_variables` and get and set its value with `eval` (though that's definitely not recommended for sanity reasons), but once it's out of scope, that's it. No way to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby we have something we could call scope gates - places when a program written in ruby leaves the previous scope. Those gates are: `class`, `module` and method (`def` keyword). In other words after `class`, `module` of `def` keyword in the code you're immediately entering into a new scope.

In ruby nested visibility doesn't happen and as soon as you create a new scope, the previous binding will be replaced with a new set of bindings.

For example if you define following class:

```
x = 1
class MyClass
  # you can't access to x from here
  def foo
    # ...from here too
    y = 1
    local_variables
  end
end
```

`local_variables` method call will return `[:y]`. It means that we don't have an access to the `x` variable. You can workaround this issue using ruby's technique called *Flat Scopes*. Basically instead defining a class using `class` keyword you can define it using `Class.new` and pass a block to this call. Obviously a block can take any local variables from the scope where it was defined since it's a closure!

Our previous example could be rewritten to something like like that:

```
x = 1
Foo = Class.new do
  define_method :foo do
    i_can_do_something_with(x)
    y = 1
    local_variables
  end
end
```

In this case `local_variables` will return `[:x, :y]`.