# How to extract values and store in arrays from a hash map in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I already have an Hash map of school which has key as student's first name. I would like to extract all information and create hash map with student's `School_ID` as primary key.
I am getting error

> undefined local variable or method 'key1' for main:object

```
key1 = Array.new
array2 = Array.new

def print_info(school_hash)         
  school_hash.each do |student|     #school_hash  has key as first name
                                    #student[0] contains First Name student[1] all info
    key1.push(student[1].School_ID) #save school_id separately to use as a key
    array2.push(student[1])         # all infos including Address, Grade, School_ID, Sports
  end
  new_hash = Hash[key1.zip(array2)]
  printf("%s",new_hash)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move key1 and array2 into the def block or pass them in as parameters.  Ruby def blocks are not closures -- they cannot access local variables defined outside of them.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a new method in ruby a new scope will be created, see: [metaprogramming access local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008009/metaprogramming-access-local-variables/10056669#10056669) for more details.

Instead of `def print_info(school_hash)` you could use lambda, for example

```
school_hash = lambda do |school_hash|
  # ..your method body
end

school_hash.call(hash)
```

Other solution - just put:

```
key1=Array.new
array2=Array.new
```

in the method's body.

Answer (score 1):

You could change `key1` to `@key1`, and `array2` to `@array2`.